# Set Default Page on Hue

Tags: django, hadoop, hue

I am new to Django. I'd like to make some edits to Hue (the Hadoop UI), and don't know what to change. I'd like to set the default page to the filebrowser, so that when a user logs in the first page they will go to is filebrowser. I know that Hue provides a redirect functionality with ?next=, but this does not work behind my VIP (when I point my VIP to the next URL, it redirects but then resolves to the true IP address rather than the virtual, which is not what I want). I'd like to hardwire changes so that the default URL is always the filebrowser, how can I do this?

My current strategy is to edit urls.py in /desktop/core/src/desktop and add the following line:

```
dynamic_patterns += patterns('filebrowser.views',
  url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py" in index
  99.   return view(request, path)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py" in view
  161.             return listdir_paged(request, path)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py" in listdir_paged
  435.     return render('listdir.mako', request, data)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py" in render
  222.                                **kwargs)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py" in _render_to_response
  144.     return django_mako.render_to_response(template, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py" in render_to_response
  117.   return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, data_dictionary), **kwargs)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py" in render_to_string_normal
  106.   result = template.render(**data_dict)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py" in render
  443.         return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py" in _render
  786.                             **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py" in _render_context
  818.         _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py" in _exec_template
  844.         callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/tmp13I5gT/filebrowser/listdir.mako.py" in render_body
  73.         __M_writer(escape(unicode( fb_components.menubar() )))
File "/tmp/tmp13I5gT/filebrowser/fb_components.mako.py" in render_menubar
  260.         __M_writer(escape(unicode(app_name)))
File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py" in __str__
  205.         raise NameError("Undefined")

Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: Undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gained some more familiarity with Django now and was able to meet my requirement. To change the page that users are shown after logging in, edit the following file:

/desktop/core/src/desktop/views.py

In here we need to edit the index function - here is the before and after:

Old:
def index(request):
  if request.user.is_superuser and request.COOKIES.get('hueLandingPage') != 'home':
    return redirect(reverse('about:index'))
  else:
    return home(request)

New:
def index(request):
  if request.user.is_superuser and request.COOKIES.get('hueLandingPage') != 'home':
    return redirect('filebrowser.views.index')
    #return redirect(reverse('about:index'))
  else:
    return redirect('filebrowser.views.index')
    #return home(request)

You can write it how you like (clearly the if condition isn't important here) but the important point is to have this function return redirect('filebrowser.views.index')

Note: I have used this workaround with Hue 3.6 and Hue 3.7